# WebRTC: Detect stream type (video/screen) for remote peer in a P2P call

Tags: google-chrome, stream, webrtc, p2p

In a P2P call, I want to know the received remote stream's type, i.e. wether its a stream from camera or if it is a screen-capture stream.
One way I figured out is by adding contentHint in the MediaTrack and reading the same at other peer's end. I tried the same and was able to add contentHint in the stream's video track( = "text"/"fluid"/"motion") but at receiver's end, the contentHint was coming blank( "") for the same stream, while Id was restored.
Kindly help!

Comment: How did you solve this?